# Apache Shindig application flow

Tags: apache-shindig

I am new to Apache Shindig and OpenSocial framework. I have downloaded the source code from Shindig's SVN at: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shindig/trunk/.

Could some one help me to understand the application flow from web.xml to other areas. I could see 5 projects common, features, gadgets, server and social-api while importing into Eclipse. What are the significance of these projects. After using mvn install, I got war file in server's target folder. Does this war enough to run the application.

I am following different sites along with shindig.apache.org.

Please help me to understand the flow of Shindig from gadget(xml) to  server side classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably post your question to dev@shindig.apache.org or users@shindig.apache.org.  With Apache projects most of the discussion happens on email lists.

All of the Maven sub-projects you see in Eclipse are used in one way or another when rendering a gadget.  At a very high level when a gadget container renders a gadget it makes a request to a servlet on the server (ifr servlet).  The servlet goes off and fetches the gadget XML and transforms it into HTML.  The HTML is then returned from the servlet and rendered in the container.  As the HTML returned from the servlet is being rendered in the browser there may be one or more requests back to other servlets on the server for javascript and css.  After the gadget is rendered the gadget may make other requests back to the server to proxy xhr request to different resources.  Again this is very high level.  If you have specific questions please send them to the mailing lists.